# Как сделать блок, имеющий заголовок с бордером и контентом?

Tags: html, css, css3

Прошу помощи с реализацией элемента.

**САБЖ:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Есть два блока, которые должны иметь адаптив и не ломаться при тесте контентом. Одинаковые по высоте.
2. У этих блоков есть бекграунд с блюром.
3. В центре блока есть "окно" без блюра с имиджем, заголовок, а также бордер, который рвется у границ заголовка.
4. Заголовок имеет прозрачный фон.
5. Под данным окном есть секция со ссылками.

Если пп 2 и 3 более менее понятно как делать, то вот с бордером и заголовком, а также одинаковой высотой самого "окна" у меня не срастается.

**ВОПРОС:** как реализовать ОКНО: данный блок должен иметь одну высоту и адаптивиться-резиниться, иметь адаптивный же бордер.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Например:

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
          box-sizing:border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #eee;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.wrap {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction:normal;
      -ms-flex-flow:row wrap;
          flex-flow:row wrap;
  
}

.card {
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  
  color:#fff;
  
  padding: 50px 50px 70px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card-1 {
  background: orangered;
}

.card-2 {
  background: grey;
}

.card:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
    
}

.card-1:after,
.bg-1 {
  background: url(http://pngimg.com/uploads/watches/watches_PNG9861.png) no-repeat 35% 10% fixed;
  
  background-size: auto 50%;
}

.card-2:after,
.bg-2 {
  background: url(https://www.sneakerfiles.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/nike-air-max-90-golf-shoes.png) no-repeat 100% 40% fixed;
  
  background-size: 35%;
}

.card:after {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
          filter: blur(5px);
}



.card a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color:inherit;
}

.card h2 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1.1;
  margin: 0;
}

.card-footer {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size:.75rem;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 50px;
}

.card-inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: 2px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}

.card h2:before,
.card h2:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
}

.card h2:before {
  height: 2px;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  right: -888px;
}

.card h2:after {
  width: 2px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -888px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="card card-1">
      
      <div class="card-inner bg-1">
        <h2>
          Nixon <br> Perimeter <br> Collection
        </h2>
      </div>
      
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="#">Lorem ipsum ></a>
      </div>
      
    </div>
    
    <div class="card card-2">
      
      <div class="card-inner bg-2">
        <h2>
          Sweetes <br> Pack of <br> Air Maxes
        </h2>
      </div>
      
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="#">Lorem ipsum ></a>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/GPENoP)

Главное взять подходящий фон ( с подходящими размерами), я применила случайные с просторов сети для примера.

[caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters)

Comment: Огромная Благодарность вам!!!

Comment: @HamSter Здравствуйте. Вы почему не предупреждаете, что CSS свойство **filter** имеет ограниченную поддержку браузерами? https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters В реальной работе, в верстке данное решение может быть не применимо, из-за отсутствие поддержки IE-11.

Comment: Я думаю о том, что кто мешает сделать два изображения, одно поверх другого. Одно будет там где контент, будет растягиваться и просто обрезаться с помощью overflow: hidden.

Comment: @HamSter `мне каждое св-во расписывать где поддерживается, а где нет?!`  Удивился я, ожидая, что напишите о том, что забыли про это указать. Мой ответ: естественно нужно предупреждать о том, IE-11 сейчас поддерживается по-умолчанию, вы человека крепко можете подставить. Да и не про каждое свойство, а вот про **filter** например, да, каждый кто хотя-бы немного вёрстку знает, сразу смекнёт насчёт него.  В CSS много что есть, да далеко не всё используется. Я бы вам минус поставил за такое отношение, но уж больно ваш пример мне нравится.

Comment: @Polina Автор уже просто принял ответ. Если напишет, что ему не подходит не кроссбраузерное решение, то я готов попробовать сделать своё, кроссбраузерное.

Comment: @HamSter С чем спорите-то вы? Что не нужно использовать caniuse.com в работе? - я говорю нужно. Говорите не нужно поддерживать IE-11, я говорю нужно. Едва ли ваша позиция может здесь устоять, потому что это неоспоримые вещи в вёрстке. `многие уже используют и grid` - такие фразы предлагаю вам оставить. Многие ? - кто эти многие, дайте пожалуйста ссылки на известные и крупные сайты, где используются CSS-свойства не поддерживаемые в IE-11? Про автопрефиксы вы зря здесь, ведь **filter** он потому зачастую и не используется из-за отсутствия поддержки в IE-11.

Comment: @HamSter Удалили свои комментарии, видимо чтобы в дурном свете не выглядеть, заявляя подобные вещи.

Comment: Коллеги... Я, мягко говоря не тупой джун и @HamSter это понимает, разумно полагая, что я в курсе про поддержку. И я БЛАГОДАРНА за это доверие. Мне нужна была помощь в решении "фундаментального" вопроса. И я его получила. То что вы тут развели - это недостойно stackoverflow.com

Comment: @HamSter кроссовки куда убегают при увеличении окна браузера? А так всё конечно здорово сделано! (+)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, картинки первые попавшиеся, поэтому "на глаз" спозиционировала)) Картинки с макета с пор. размерами думаю проще будет расположить, чтобы не убегали))